# python: pytz package installation issue: ImportError: No module named pytz

Tags: python, installation, importerror, pytz

I installed the pytz package on my windows7 machine via:

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\pytz>easy_install --upgrade pytz
Searching for pytz
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/
Reading http://pytz.sourceforge.net
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=79122
Reading http://www.stuartbishop.net/Software/pytz
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/
Best match: pytz 2013b
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pytz/pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg#md5=7cfcc57ddb87125a042b70c03580d6cf
Processing pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg
Moving pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding pytz 2013b to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pytz
Finished processing dependencies for pytz

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 485C-3867
```

I checked that the .egg file is in the python27\lib\site-packages directory:

```
 Directory of C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

04/05/2013  06:06 PM    <DIR>          .
04/05/2013  06:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/05/2013  06:06 PM               237 easy-install.pth
09/20/2006  10:05 AM               126 easy_install.py
04/05/2013  05:33 PM               312 easy_install.pyc
04/05/2013  05:33 PM               312 easy_install.pyo
10/19/2009  06:35 AM            85,435 pkg_resources.py
04/05/2013  05:33 PM            90,779 pkg_resources.pyc
04/05/2013  05:33 PM            90,779 pkg_resources.pyo
04/05/2013  06:06 PM           521,259 pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg
03/08/2011  10:39 AM               121 README.txt
04/05/2013  05:33 PM    <DIR>          setuptools
04/05/2013  05:33 PM    <DIR>          setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
09/20/2006  10:05 AM             2,362 site.py
04/05/2013  05:33 PM             1,719 site.pyc
04/05/2013  05:33 PM             1,719 site.pyo
04/05/2013  05:36 PM         1,784,796 sqlalchemy-0.8.0-py2.7.egg
04/05/2013  05:27 PM    <DIR>          xlrd
04/05/2013  05:27 PM               975 xlrd-0.7.3-py2.7.egg-info
```

But when I go to the python interpreter I get:

```
>>>import pytz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

When I open up a .py file in PyDev it claims that the `import pytz` statement is unresolved. It can't find the package.

I would kindly appreciate some help. Thank you.

**EDIT **

The contents of `easy_install.pth`:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./sqlalchemy-0.8.0-py2.7.egg
./pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

I removed the `./pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg` from the `easy_install.pth` file and tried `easy_install pytz`. This time it installed and I can `import pytz` without the error reported earlier (why would this fix the issue?).

HOWEVER, my ecplise/pydev still does not seem to acknowledge the `import pytz` statement. It can't resolve it. It also can't resolve `import sqlalchemy` but the dos python interpreter can import both. The python interpreter in eclipse/pydev is set to `C:\Python27\python.exe` if you go to `Windows > Preferences > Interpreter - Python`.

Interesting enough I had to check my interpreter configuration in the *project*. I just assumed that the project would know given the global settings. But I guess not.

Now everything works. Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: Anyone know how I can fix/troubleshoot this? Appreciate it.

Comment: What are the contents of ``easy_install.pth``?

Comment: what is the value of `sys.executable` after running `import sys`?  On Windows, sometimes the python that runs scripts is not the same as your command line python.

Comment: i get `C:\\Python27\\python.exe` when I run the commands you suggeted.

Comment: I removed the `./pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg` from the `easy_install.pth` file and tried `easy_install pytz`. This time it installed and I can `import pytz` without the error reported. HOWEVER, my ecplise/pydev does not seem to acknowledge the `import pytz` statement. It can't resolve it. The python interpreter is set to `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

Comment: Still didn't understand how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Check that your egg doesn't have any funky permissions set on it.
2. Is that your only Python install in C? `import sys; sys.executable` to check which is being run.
3. Do you have other eggs that you *are* able to import?

Comment: i get `C:\\Python27\\python.exe` when I run the commands you suggeted.

Comment: I have another python install but thats for cygwin. I was able to fix the problem by deleting the `./pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg` line in the easy_install.pth file and re-running `easy_install`. That worked. I am still having problems with pydev/eclipse despite it pointing to the `C:\Python27\python.exe` interpreter.

Comment: @algotr8der did you rescan for packages after installing pytz? In pydev: preferences -> interpreter - python, then hit Apply.

Comment: Yeah I did do that but it still didnt resolve the pytz until I went into the project configuration and removed/added-back the interpreter settings. Strange because I thought it would have absorbed the global settings which were rescanned. In any case, things work now. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @algotr8der what do u mean removed/added-back the interpreter settings? I am now exactly in the same problem so i want to take your advice. Could u give me an advice?